# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1 Error

Tags: android, exception

I am using `ListView` to dynamically add checkboxes in Android. I am using a `ContextAdapter` class to add inflate the `ListView`.
My error log is as follows:

```
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): Process: com.project.attendancemanager, PID: 1192
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192): android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:244)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3888)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.project.attendancemanager.CustomAdapter.getView(CustomAdapter.java:31)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2263)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.ListView.measureHeightOfChildren(ListView.java:1263)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.ListView.onMeasure(ListView.java:1175)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.measureChild(RelativeLayout.java:689)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onMeasure(RelativeLayout.java:473)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onMeasure(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:327)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5125)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:310)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:2291)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16497)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:1916)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1113)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1295)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1000)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:5670)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:761)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:574)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:544)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:747)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
09-23 13:44:45.000: E/AndroidRuntime(1192):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

`ContextAdapter` class is as follows:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.CheckBox;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<ListData>{

    ListData[] items = null;
    Context context;

    public CustomAdapter(Context context, ListData[] resource) {
        super(context, R.layout.activity_list_row, resource);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        this.context = context;
        this.items = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        LayoutInflater inflator = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
        convertView = inflator.inflate(R.layout.activity_list_row, parent, false);
        TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.NameTV);
        TextView rollNo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.RollNoTV);
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.studentCB);
        name.setText(items[position].getName());
        rollNo.setText(items[position].getRollNo());

        if(items[position].getValue() == 1)
            cb.setChecked(true);
        else
            cb.setChecked(false);

        return convertView;
    }   
}
```

My `ListData` class:

```
package com.project.attendancemanager;

public class ListData {

    String name;
    int value, rollno;

    ListData(String name, int rollno, int value){
        this.name = name;
        this.rollno = rollno;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return this.name;
    }

    public int getRollNo(){ 
        return this.rollno;
    }

    public int getValue(){  
        return this.value;
    }

}
```

Inside the `onCreate` function in the Activity I am doing this:

```
Listview lv;
ListData[] items;
CustomAdapter adapter = new CustomAdapter(this, items);
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

It would be of great help is someone could point out the mistake in my code.
Thanks! Cheers!

Answer (score 184, accepted):

Instead of

```
rollNo.setText(items[position].getRollNo());
```

you should use

```
rollNo.setText(Integer.toString(items[position].getRollNo()));
```

If you try to set integer as text, you call method setText(int resID) and application try to set as text some string resource with this resID.

Comment: User String.valueOf(int); otherwise showing below warning :
When calling TextView#setText * Never call Number#toString() to format numbers; it will not handle fraction separators and locale-specific digits properly. Consider using String#format with proper format specifications (%d or %f) instead. * Do not pass a string literal (e.g. "Hello") to display text. Hardcoded text can not be properly translated to other languages. Consider using Android resource strings instead. * Do not build messages by concatenating text chunks. Such messages can not be properly translated.

Comment: Weird that the IDE doesn't show a problem there. Only shows an error when hard coding an Int value like `rollNo.setText(123);`

Answer (score 8):

**SetText doesnt allow integer values**

Just Add `""+` for your code to look like this `""+rollNo.setText(items[position].getRollNo());`

this error occurs because setText does not take Integers, it takes Strings

Answer (score 4):

You can also use

```
String.valueOf()
```

in your code to avoid the Resource Not Found Exception .

Your code will look like this

```
rollNo.setText(String.valueOf(items[position].getRollNo()));
```

It will work perfectly fine because the SetText() only requires **strings** as values to be passed on.

Answer (score 0):

This might help as well,

write like this -> `textView.setText("" + cartModels.size());`

instead of -> `textView.setText(cartModels.size());`

```
   TextView cartText = view.findViewById(R.id.cartTextDemo);

   CartViewModel cartViewModel = ViewModelProviders.of(this).get(CartViewModel.class);
   cartViewModel.getmAllCartsVM().observe(this, new Observer<List<CartModel>>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable List<CartModel> cartModels) {

            if (cartModels != null) {
                //cartText.setText(cartModels.size()); // This will not work beacuse it is getting resource instead of string
                  cartText.setText("" + cartModels.size()); // this will give string
                Log.d(TAG, "onChanged: onChanged Called: CartModels Count: "+cartModels.size());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: I can't really see how this answer differs from Ismael ozil's previous answer. I'd also add that the accepted answer does the same thing in (IMHO) a cleaner and more easily-readable manner.

Comment: that's right but my thought was to give another example apart from the question's solution for better understanding. For some one facing this issue first time the question is too big to read but for understanding it's good.