# android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException on setImageResource

Tags: java, android

I am working on an app where I have a recyclerview in a fragment and a viewpager in other activity so now I am passing image from recyclerview to viewpager but the problem is when I click on recyclerview I'm getting resource not found exception.

For this I searched on the internet and I found this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26001780/android-content-res-resourcesnotfoundexception-string-resource-id-0x1-error?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) but it doesn't solve the problem as it is just suggesting to use String.valueof and I cant do that on setImageresource.

So I don't understand where I'm going wrong so please someone can guide me here.
So here is the code for recyclerview

```
  class VH extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener{
            ImageView iv;
            TextView tv;
            HWRatioContainer ivc;
            Context context;
            int[] images;
            CustomButton top_recycler_button;
            public VH(View itemView,Context context,int[] images) {
                super(itemView);
                iv = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv);
                this.context = context;
                this.images = images;
                top_recycler_button = (CustomButton)itemView.findViewById(R.id.top_recycler_button);
                itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
                //tv = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.tv);
                ///ivc = (HWRatioContainer) itemView.findViewById(R.id.ivc);
               /*ivc.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onGlobalLayout() {
                        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
                            ivc.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                        } else {
                            ivc.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
                        }
                        ivc.setTranslationX(ivc.getWidth() >> 4);
                    }
                });*/

            }

            @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(context,DetailsActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("slider_image",images[getAdapterPosition()]);
                intent.putExtra("transition_name", ViewCompat.getTransitionName(iv));

                Pair<View,String> pair = Pair.create((View)iv,iv.getTransitionName());
                ActivityOptionsCompat compat = ActivityOptionsCompat.makeSceneTransitionAnimation
                        ((Activity)context,pair);
                context.startActivity(intent,compat.toBundle());
            }
        }
```

and here is the code for viewpager

```
 @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT)
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position) {
        layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.custom_dots_layout,null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.detail_viewpager_image);
        Intent intent  = new Intent();
        imageView.setImageResource(intent.getIntExtra("slider_image",1));


        ViewPager viewPager1 = (ViewPager)container;
        viewPager1.addView(view,0);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(@NonNull ViewGroup container, int position, @NonNull Object object) {
        ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager)container;
        View view =  (View)object;
        viewPager.removeView(view);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are setting the string value to array of integer, so there is an error.

Comment: So how should i getintent in image resource @Sam

Comment: `Intent intent  = new Intent();` - That's not the `Intent` that started the `ViewPager` `Activity`, so it won't have your extra on it. You need to call `getIntent()` on the `Activity`.

Comment: but my image is in the viewpager so how do i set image resource to viewpager in activity @MikeM.

Comment: You could add an `int` parameter to the `PagerAdapter`'s constructor, or create a setter method for it, etc. I'm not really sure why you're using a `ViewPager` for a single image, though.

Comment: Ahh.. as @MikeM.pointed, you are going no where with intent. Shared prefrences may be.. you can try.

Comment: Thank you @MikeM. i did as you suggested and it worked.

Comment: @MikeM. i have one more issue could you suggest me something

Comment: Possibly, if it's relatively quick.

Comment: Actually i made a another recyclerview in different activity and used linearsnaphelper using this SO post stackoverflow.com/questions/29134094/… but now it doesnt consider the last and first item in recyclerview so i dont know what should i do to center each item like viewpager so can you suggest me something @MikeM.

Comment: Oo, that's probably gonna need a whole 'nother question, but did you try the `PagerSnapHelper` instead? I've not used it yet, so I'm not sure if it'll fix your issue, but it was created specifically to mimic `ViewPager`, so I would hope it does.

Comment: Yes @MikeM. i used PagerSnaphelper as well but still i doesnt work like viewpager

Comment: Yeah, sorry, you'll have to post a new question for that. I only used `LinearSnapHelper` once or twice, a while ago, and I've never used `PagerSnapHelper`, so I really wouldn't be able to suggest anything.