# My Android app quit unexpectedly when I invoke setAdapter() to the recycleView

Tags: android, sqlite, android-recyclerview

I use the android room to save my data , and it I could get the data from database successfully . However , when I invoke setAdapter() ,the app crash .
Here is my code of Adapter

```
public class QueryAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<QueryAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
     List<Student> localData;

    public  class  MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView id,name,sex,address,major;
        public MyViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            id = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_id);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_name);
            sex = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_sex);
            address = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_address);
            major = itemView.findViewById(R.id.show_major);
        }
    }

    public QueryAdapter(List<Student> students){
        this.localData = students;
    }
    @NonNull
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.query_item, parent, false);

        return new MyViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.id.setText(localData.get(position).id);
        holder.major.setText(localData.get(position).major);
        holder.sex.setText(localData.get(position).sex);
        holder.address.setText(localData.get(position).address);
        holder.name.setText(localData.get(position).name);

    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return this.localData.size();
    }
}
```

This is the code where I use the recycleView

```
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        localData = studentDao.loadAllStudent();
        QueryAdapter myAdapter = new QueryAdapter(localData);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(myAdapter);
```

the log is like this , It says there is something wrong with my onBindViewHolder(),but I don't know why it can't work.

```
2021-05-06 17:31:35.495 25980-25980/com.example.homework_2021_5_6 E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.homework_2021_5_6, PID: 25980
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
        at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:444)
        at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:6436)
        at com.example.homework_2021_5_6.adapter.QueryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(QueryAdapter.java:46)
        at com.example.homework_2021_5_6.adapter.QueryAdapter.onBindViewHolder(QueryAdapter.java:16)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.onBindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7065)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.bindViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:7107)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryBindViewHolderByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6012)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:6279)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6118)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:6114)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2303)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1627)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1587)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:665)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:4134)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3851)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4404)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6419)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6419)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6419)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:446)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6419)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6419)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1829)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1673)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1582)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6419)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:332)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:270)
        at com.android.internal.policy.DecorView.onLayout(DecorView.java:820)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:23042)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:6419)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:3786)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:3227)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:2182)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8730)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:1352)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:1149)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:1049)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameHandler.handleMessage(Choreographer.java:1275)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:233)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8010)
2021-05-06 17:31:35.495 25980-25980/com.example.homework_2021_5_6 E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:631)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:978)
2021-05-06 17:31:35.554 25980-25980/com.example.homework_2021_5_6 I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 25980 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Share logs so people can narrow down the causes.

Comment: Difficult to say which line is failing, but apparently a view ID is incorrect. Post your layout (for the viewHolder) and did you debug this? are the `findViewById` returning references or null? Unrelated: `show_sex` and `sex` should really be `show_gender` and `gender` unless this app is targeted at adults and their sex lives :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key is that a resource you're trying to assign to a TextView doesn't exist. This can be due to many factors:

1. You are trying to assign something that doesn't exist: `textView.setText = R.string.does_not_exist`
2. You're trying to assign a text that are numbers:

```
someTextView.setText(1)
```

^ Android will think `1` is a resource id and will try to find it.

Instead, you should either cast it or pass a string

```
someTextView.setText("1")

or

someTextView.setText(1.toString())
```

It's likely that one of these:

```
setText(localData.get(position).xxxx)
```

Has a number in it, and the setText(...) method you're actually invoking is this one:

```
    /**
     * Sets the text to be displayed using a string resource identifier.
     *
     * @param resid the resource identifier of the string resource to be displayed
     *
     * @see #setText(CharSequence)
     *
     * @attr ref android.R.styleable#TextView_text
     */
    @android.view.RemotableViewMethod
    public final void setText(@StringRes int resid) {
        setText(getContext().getResources().getText(resid));
        mTextSetFromXmlOrResourceId = true;
        mTextId = resid;
    }
```

Instead of

```
  public final void setText(CharSequence text) {
        setText(text, mBufferType);
    }
```

Comment: thanks a lot .I learn a lot from your answer.

Answer (score 1):

In your onBindViewHolder() method:

Instead of,

**holder.id.setText(localData.get(position).id);**

Use:

**holder.id.setText(Integer.toString(localData.get(position).id));**

You should visit this https://stackoverflow.com/a/26001905/12660050